# Slide navigation view left to right - Sencha touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

When pushing new View, this view slides from left to right. But Navigation View elements (title, buttons) slide from right to left.

I'd like to achieve same effect as pressed Back button has.

Here is the code I'm using for sliding the Views:

```
            navigationView.animateActiveItem(view, {
                    type: 'slide', 
                    direction: 'right'
                });

            navigationView.push(view);
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the animation you want to use direction on the `Ext.navigation.View`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.navigation.View', {
    fullscreen : true,
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'right'
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#8b5Au)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But I need to animate it dymanically depending on which side the button is. I tried `navigationView.setLayout().setAnimation()` but the error has been thrown: `[ERROR][Ext.Container#setLayout] Replacing a layout after one has already been initialized is not currently supported.`

Comment: You should try navigationView.getLayout().setAnimation() and not navigationView.setLayout().setAnimation()

Comment: Ooh you're right :) I've changed it but navigationView slides from  right to instead of left to right.